# Create and delete triple pointer of dimensions [3N][N][3] with N=2, mysterious seg fault

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, delete-operator

I have a problem programming in **C++**, I want to create and delete a triple pointer with dimension [3N][N][3], and I keep getting seg-fault without knowing in which line the error is...(N is an integer, N=2 to start)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int N=2;

int main(void){

double ***individuo;
individuo=new double**[3*N];
for(int k=0; k<3*N; ++k){
    individuo[k]=new double*[3];
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i){
        individuo[k][i]=new double[N];
    }
}

for(int k=0; k<3*N; ++k){
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i){
        delete []individuo[k][i];
    }
    delete []individuo[k];
}
delete []individuo;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: on what line do you segfault ? also actually , you create double[3N][3][N]

Comment: it does not say in what line the seg fault is...the N is an global variable I need, that set the size of the pointers...

Comment: `I keep getting seg fault without knowing in witch line the error is` So what prevented you from opening up your debugger?

Comment: if `N` is always going to be known at compile-time, consider using `std::array`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - look, you are a debugging slave like the rest of us.  If we cannot answer with working code ASAP, we have to shut up because 'that is not contributing' :(((((

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your first set of `for` loops is setting up the array with dimensions `[3N][3][N]`, and then your second set is calling them as if it was dimensioned as `[3N][N][]`. This means that you aren't correctly accounting for all your allocated memory in the `delete` process.

You can use a debugger to find out where your code is giving the segfault. Or if you don't have one it's often useful to put in some unique print statements at various stages to try and find where it is giving the fault. Although make sure that the print statements are flushed from the buffer, most easily done using `std::endl`.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
for(int k=0; k<3*N; ++k){
    individuo[k]=new double*[3];
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i){
        individuo[k][i]=new double[N];
    }
}
```

should instead be this

```
for(int k=0; k<3*N; ++k){
    individuo[k]=new double*[N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i){
        individuo[k][i]=new double[3];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the right answer  (I've upvoted too many answers today apparently, so here's a comment instead)